# Use of NavigationDrawer for multiple Activities

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a requirement to use NavigationnDrawer in my project.

Question: considering my app has multiple Activities (some has master/detail fragments)

The master/detail fragment would have single container layout for tablets and large width devices and  2 different layouts on smaller width for master & detail views.
What can be right direction to proceed (1) or (2) or any different advice which makes more sense?

1. Every activity has a NavigationDrawer and it's layout rendered using setContentView(layourID) in OnCreate().
2. All activities extends a Base Activity which uses NavigationDrawer.

If answer is (2) please provide some more useful advice. And if it's something else , please do share .

Answer (score 0):

I think this tutorial may help you. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8hSIP2ha-g  and also refer this http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/

Comment: Well the links teaches how to create navigationdrawer, which is not my question , I am looking for Navigationdrawer in context of app with multiple activities wherein each activity might have master-detail fragments and the rendering would change on device and tablet as per the width.